# Docker cache storage location

Tags: docker, redhat

I've Docker running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo), and using `overlay2` as the storage driver. Upon running `docker info`, the docker storage location is shown as `Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker`.

I want to know which location is responsible for making `docker run` (or pull) commands faster, by utilizing the existing cache. I believe the message shown like this `89e1bee20d9: Already exists` while doing a `docker run` happens due to a certain directory or location with `var/lib/docker`.

The directories inside `/var/lib/docker` are as below.
- containers
- image
- network
- overlay2
- plugins
- swarm
- tmp
- trust
- volumes

Comment: It doesn't depend on directories. You can see all images with `docker images` and all running container with `docker ps`. Please make sure if the container is already running which you are trying to run or if the image already exists which you are trying to pull.

Comment: It's an implementation detail, in the same class of question as "which directory in `/var/lib/postgres` has my database table": it's complicated and you really shouldn't be manually making changes there.  In the case of Docker it will also differ by installation.